# Taylor Polynomial of $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

What is $P_4$, the 4th degree Taylor Polynomial of $e^{-x^2}$ around $x=0$?

I thought I try: $u=-x^2$

So for $e^u$: $P_4(u)=1+u+\frac{u^2}{2!}+\frac{u^3}{3!}+\frac{u^4}{4!}$

Therefore I thought for $e^{-x^2}$: $P_4(x)=1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}-\frac{x^6}{3!}+\frac{x^8}{4!}$

But... apparently the right answer is for $e^{-x^2}$: $P_4(x)=1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}$

What is my mistake? Why is the last answer the right answer?

Comment: *Your* taylor polynomial is of degree $8$

Comment: $6>4$  and  $8>4$. ?

Comment: @b00nheT What do you mean by "my" taylor polynomial? And why is it of degree $8$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is $P_4(x) = 1 - x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2!}$?

Because that is the **degree 4** Taylor polynomial. You gave the degree 8 Taylor polynomial.

Comment: How do you 'decide' which polynomial is which degree?

Comment: @ImreVégh I'm not quite sure what you mean. The degree of a polynomial is a well-defined concept, and it refers to the largest degree of a monomial in the expression for the polynomial. Here, the monomial of largest degree is $x^4 / 2!$, which has degree $4$. Thus the degree of the polynomial is $4$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial

Answer (score 2):

Simply because `4th degree` does not mean `with 4 powers of x`.

Comment: Then what does it mean?

Comment: You've written a polynomial of degree $8$, not $4$. For the substitution $u=-x^2$, you had to expand $\mathrm e^u$ at order $2$. If the substitution had been $u=x^4$, you'd have to expand it at order $1$.